# Server 2016 MSMQ failover

Tags: failover, msmq

I would like to setup a MSMQ in a failover system.

I do not have a shared storage setup (hardware not available - budget),
but i have three dl380 running windows server 2016.

I would like to setup failover with a quorum server.

is this setup possible?

Comment: Looks like the coin will be killing this entire project.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also stick with Always On scenario that doesnt assume a shared storage and where the overall health of your cluster would be determined by the votes of quorum of nodes in the cluster. But this feature is an enterprise one. So in case of tight budget, I would also recommend to go with FCIs.

Comment: AlwaysOn is available with an inexpensive Standard edition of SQL Server. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt614935.aspx (OK, these are BASIC Availability Groups but should be enough for most of the cases IMHO).

Comment: Too much limitations, if you ask me. I'd reconsider going this way referring to "limit of two replicas" and "no support for adding or removing a replica to an existing availability group".

Comment: Yeah, we do FCI over basic AGs here.

Comment: Does this Always On SQL server allow the MSMQ to carry over as well?

Comment: AFAIK, MSMQ doesn't implement the "always-on" feature, so the some sort of shared disk is still a requirement for the quorum. But it may be even a JBOD enclosure or a replicated drive.

Answer (score 10):

From my experience, MSMQ deploys find on top of clustered shared volumes. Therefore, any software shared solution that does mirror/present storage to Failover cluster as CSV will do the job.

I can recommend you try [HPE VSA](https://www.hpe.com/us/en/storage/storevirtual.html), [StarWind VSAN](https://www.starwindsoftware.com/starwind-virtual-san-free), [Microsoft Storage Spaces Direct](https://www.google.com.ua/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwid4fOLkqnSAhXlPZoKHdkUBH0QFggaMAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Ftechnet.microsoft.com%2Fen-us%2Fwindows-server-docs%2Fstorage%2Fstorage-spaces%2Fstorage-spaces-direct-overview&usg=AFQjCNEa1PbGRAlNiFDQIbW_kSu72Pl_3A), so far all of them do share nothing storage for Failover Cluster. I would suggest StarWind in case you don't run Hyper-V on your hosts, so it will do free mirrored storage.